# In Java why we need an object to call a function in the main function of the same class but no object for other function which is not main?

Tags: java, oop, getter-setter

I would like to give an example:

```
    1 public class Ticket
    2 {
    3     private int ticketid;
    4     private  int price;
    5     private  int availableTickets;
    6     public void setTicketid(int ticketid)
    7     {
    8         this.ticketid=ticketid;
    9     }
   10     public void setPrice(int price)
   11     {
   12         this.price=price;
   13         
   14     }
   15     public  void setAvailableTickets(int availableTickets)
   16     {
   17         if(availableTickets>0)
   18         {
   19             this.availableTickets=availableTickets;
   20         }
   21     }
   22     public int getTicketid()
   23     {
   24         return ticketid;
   25     }
   26     public int getPrice()
   27     {
   28         return price;
   29     }
   30     public  int getAvailableTickets()
   31     {
   32         return availableTickets;
   33     }
   34     public int calculateTicketCost(int nooftickets)
   35     {
   36         
   37         int at=getAvailableTickets();
   38         int ans;
   39         int p;
   40         if(nooftickets<at)
   41         {
   42             at=at-nooftickets;
   43             setAvailableTickets(at);
   44              p=getPrice();
   45             System.out.println(p+"p");
   46             ans=nooftickets*p;
   47             return ans;
   48             
   49         }
   50         else
   51         {
   52             return -1;
   53         }
   54     }
   55 }
```

Why can we use `getAvailableTickets()`, `setAvailableTickets()`, and `getPrice()`
without an object in the calculateTicketCost() function, but if we tried those methods in the main method instead of calculateTicketCost(), we would have needed an object to use those three functions.

Please tell me why an object isn't needed. Tysm.

Comment: Those functions are called on the object itself (the original one you created in `main()` and called `calculateTicketCost()` with). It is the same as `this.getAvailableTickets()`, etc.

Comment: Every application needs someplace to start. That place is `main()`. After `main()` creates some objects, the objects can reference each other and can reference themselves (as in the example here) and can create even more objects. To say it another way, every application has to start in the same place; but once it has started it can go anywhere; and it can forget about `main()` from that point on.

Answer (score 1):

Because the main method is outside the class and so you have to create an instance of the class with which you can access the methods of the class

and if your main method is within the class, you can use the methods in the main method without creating an object, but your methods must be `static`

Also check this please [Java OOP](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_oop.asp)

Comment: I really wanted to up-click your answer. It is *almost* right. The issue I have is where you state "if your main method is within the class..." depending on public/protected etc declaration, you can call static methods in any class, not just the one the main is in

Answer (score 1):

*static* methods exist in an object-less "this"-less context. You have only static variables, method parameters, and other static methods to draw on. *Non-static* methods have an object/data context.

An example of using object methods: You have an Employee method. That Employee's name, ID, etc is specific to that Employee.

An example of a static method: Convert an angle from degrees to radians. This method doesn't need a context - it just needs a degrees parameter

Answer (score 0):

In a static context, you can call static methods without creating an instance.
Your question is why you can not access the nonstatic method without creating an instance from a static context.

The static method is common (Fixed and constant) to every instance possibly you can declare. All the nonstatic methods can access the same static method. On the other hand, if you want to call a nonstatic method from a static method which nonstatic method you want to call? There is no non-static method that exists in memory before the instance of the class is created. You can create many copies of them by instanciting the class and then you can access them in a static context.

Secondly,
You can access a nonstatic method from another nonstatic method without creating an instance. Why does it happen? It happens because the nonstatic method only comes to existence when one creates an instance of the corresponding class. And when you create an instance that means both methods exist in that instance and they can access eachother without.